# Question about whether a set is a generator for the Borel sigma-algebra on R

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I have given a generator system / set defined as:

$\mathcal{H}=[-a,a], a>0$. I need to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{H})$ does not generate the Borel sigma-algebra. To do so I first need to show that $[0,1]\notin \sigma(\mathcal{H})$. To do this I have been given the following hint:

Let $X$ be a set and let $F \subseteq X$. Define

$\Sigma_F:=\{A\subseteq X:A\cap F=F \;\text{or}\;A\cap F= \emptyset\}$

It follows (no need to show it) that $\Sigma_F$ is a sigma-algebra on $X$.

Now, the idea is the following: 1) show that $\mathcal{H} \in \Sigma_F$ and that $[0,1]\notin \Sigma_F$, which means that $[0,1]\notin \sigma(\mathcal{H})$, and hence $\mathcal{H}$ cannot be a generator for the Borel sigma-algebra.

The big deal is to pick a subset F such that the above holds. I am to do this such that F does not depend on a (I have not been able to come up with a solution myself).

I have tried e.g. $F = [0,2]$. This means that $[0,1]\cap F=[0,1]$ and is thus not in $\Sigma_F$. But it does not satisfy the other condition, i.e. $H \cap F=F\; \text{or}\; H\cap F = \emptyset$. Now obviously if I could set $F=[-a,0]$ we would be all good.

Do you have any ideas as to how to solve this?

Comment: It is equivalent to show it for $\mathcal{G}= (-a,a), a>0$ if anyone has a better idea using the generator system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that choosing $F$ to be an interval won't work because we would always be able to find another interval that has a non-trivial intersection with it (e.g. take $[-m,m]$ where $m$ is the midpoint of $F$).

Now, the key idea is to exploit the symmetry of the sets in $\mathcal H$.  We know that $x \in [-a,a]$ if and only if $-x \in [-a,a]$.  Based on this observation, we set $F := \{-\frac 12, \frac 12\}$.  To verify this satisfies the desired properties, we first check $F \cap [0,1] = \{\frac 12\},$ so $[0,1] \not \in \Sigma_F$.  Now, if $a < \frac 12$, then $F \cap [-a,a] = \emptyset$.  If $a \ge \frac 12$, then $F \cap [-a,a] = F$.  Therefore, $\mathcal H \subseteq \Sigma_F \subsetneq \mathcal B$, so $\sigma(\mathcal H) \ne \mathcal B$.